# Treat elements in for loop as objects, not strings

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to use a for-loop that treats the elements in a vector as objects.

```
df <- tibble(hallo1 = "test", hallo2.1 = "test", bye1 = "test", bye2.1 = "test")
segmente <- c("hallo", "bye")

for(i in segmente){
  assign(i, df[grepl(i, names(df))]) # first step
  assign(paste0(i, "_1"), i[!grepl("\\.", names(i))]) # second step
}
```

The first step in the for-loop works as intended and creates the objects hallo and bye as tibbles. The second step does not work as intended, because, i'm assuming, that in

```
i[!grepl("\\.", names(i))]
```

the i is treated as a string, and not as the created elements hallo and bye, resulting in empy strings, while they should be tibbles as well, only containing the columns without a ".".

How can i write it so the i is identified at what it is, a created object in the first step?

Comment: `i` has not names. And `i` is not a vector (what did you mean when write `i[...]`)

Comment: in the second step, "i" should be two tibbles, hallo and bye, which i wanna subset with the [ ... ] brackets. But the code identifies them as two strings.

Comment: Try `get(i)[!grepl("\\.", names(get(i)))]` cause `i` is not a tibble.

Comment: that seems to be working. do you want to submit it as an answer?

Comment: I don't know rules of this community. I can submit it as answer, but is it a good way?

Comment: i am not sure, but i like your answer and i would accept it as such. so thank you any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first step of loop `i` is "hallo" and has no names. If you want to call tibble with name "hallo" use `get(i)`.